# Azure blob read SAS token throws AuthorizationPermissionMismatch exception

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-sas

I'm trying to generate a SAS token for a blob, so that any user with the token can read the blob. Below is the code I have. I get an exception when I try to read the blob. If I grant "Storage Blob Data Reader" access to the user, then it works. My understanding is that user with SAS token should be able to read the blob without granting specific permission. what am I missing here ?

```
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            UserDelegationKey key = await blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKeyAsync(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                                                               DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1));
            BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = "containerName",
                BlobName = "file.json",
                Resource = "b",
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
            };

           
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);
            string sasToken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(key, "accountname").ToString();
            UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder()
            {
                Scheme = "https",
                Host = string.Format("{0}.blob.core.windows.net", "accountname"),
                Path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", "containerName", "file.json"),
                Query = sasToken
            };

            var blobClient = new Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient(fullUri.Uri);

            using (var stream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync())  // throws exception 
            { }
```

Exception : Service request failed.
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Comment: What Azure RBAC roles are assigned to the user for which you are getting the user delegation key and SAS token?

Comment: @GauravMantri The user generating the SAS token is the 'Owner' of the storage account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting this error is because the user for which you are getting the user delegation key does not have permissions to access the data in the storage account.

Assigning `Owner` permission enables the user to manage the storage account itself, it does not give them permissions to manage the data.

Please try by assigning the user one of the data roles described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#azure-built-in-roles-for-blobs.

To learn more about RBAC roles to manage data, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal.

Comment: I didn't assign the 'owner' permission to the user who is trying to read the blob. The client which creates the SAS token has owner permission. In fact , my question is 'Should I grant rbac role for the user to read the blob when the user has SAS token' ? . Because the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet  says "Any client that possesses a valid SAS can access data in your storage account as permitted by that SAS"

Comment: When you generate a SAS token with user delegation key, the credentials used for user delegation key should have proper permissions. So it's not the user who is going to use the SAS token who needs to have permissions, it's the user who is generating the SAS token who needs the proper permissions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Got it. So the user who is generating the SAS needs the permission, for instance "Storage Blob Data Contributor" , so that the client who is using the SAS token could read the blob.  Thanks

Comment: That’s exactly right. This is why SAS tokens generated using User Delegation Key are more secured than the ones generated using account key.

Comment: The Role "Storage Blob Delegator" did not suffice for me to be able to generate a working SAS. I got cryptic errors and the GUI message "You don't have permissions to grant read access. You can still create a shared access signature, but you'll need an RBAC role with additional permissions before you can grant that level of access to your signature recipient." 
The solution was to grant "Storage Blob Data Owner" instead of the insufficient "Storage Blob Delegator" - Even microsofts learn article is misleading on this